# Структура с константами

Tags: golang

Вот возник такой вопрос, хочу сделать структуру для хранения набора строк с константами, можно ли объявить структуру сразу заполненную константами, или может есть другие какое-то решение для этой задачи.

Comment: А просто сделать пакет с нужными константами?

Comment: так это уже пакет, хотелось изобразить некое подобие #define из плюсов

Comment: Есть такая фраза - на любом языке можно писать как на фортране. Тут аналогично - не нужно пытаться писать на go как на c/c++ - ничего хорошего с этого скорее всего не получится.

Comment: я не пишу на плюсах, просто привёл аналог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам нужна просто анонимная структура

пример https://play.golang.org/p/7ESVPYEw3BA

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    consts := struct {
        a, b, c, d string
    }{
        a: "hello",
        b: "привет",
        c: "yo yo",
    }

    fmt.Println(consts.a)
    fmt.Println(consts.b)
    fmt.Println(consts.c)

}
```